# Using max function, group by and join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `disksinfo` (
  `idx` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hostinfo_idx` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` char(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` char(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `size` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `freespace` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idx`)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `hostinfo` (
  `idx` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `host_idx` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `probetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `processor_load` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `memory_total` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `memory_free` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idx`)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `hosts` (
  `idx` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` char(30) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`idx`)
)
```

Basicaly, hosts ist just fixed list of hostnames used in hostinfo table (hostinfo.host_idx = hosts.idx)
hostinfo is a table which is filled each few minutes with data from all hosts and in addition, for each hostinfo row at least one diskinfo row is created. Each diskinfo row contains informations about at least one disk (so, for some hosts there are 3-4 rows of diskinfo). diskinfo.hostinfo_idx = hostinfo.idx.
hostinfo.probetime is simply the time at which data snapshot was created.

What i want to perform now is to select last hostinfo (.probetime) for each particular distinct host (hostinfo.host_idx), while joing informations about disks (diskinfo table) and host names (hosts table)

I came with this:

```
SELECT hinfo.idx,
       hinfo.host_idx,
       hinfo.processor_load,
       hinfo.memory_total,
       hinfo.memory_free,
       hnames.idx,
       hnames.name,
       disks.hostinfo_idx,
       disks.id,
       disks.name,
       disks.size,
       disks.freespace,
       Max(hinfo.probetime)
FROM   systeminfo.hostinfo AS hinfo
       INNER JOIN systeminfo.hosts AS hnames
               ON hnames.idx = hinfo.host_idx
       INNER JOIN systeminfo.disksinfo AS disks
               ON disks.hostinfo_idx = hinfo.idx
GROUP  BY disks.id,
          hnames.name
ORDER  BY hnames.name,
          disks.id
```

It seems to work! But, is it 100% correct? Is it optimal? Thanks for any tip!

Comment: If you need max(hinfo.probetime) dependent row then your row will not give 100% expected result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not 100% correct, no.

Suppose you have this table:

```
x   |   y   |   z
-----------------
a       b       1
a       c       2
d       e       1
d       f       2
```

Now when you only group by x, the rows are collapsing and MySQL picks a random row from the collapsed ones. So you might get

```
x   |   y   |   z
-----------------
a       b       2
d       e       2
```

or this

```
x   |   y   |   z
-----------------
a       c       2
d       f       2
```

Or another combination, this is not determined. Each time you fire your query you might get a different result. The `2` in column `z` is always there, because of the `MAX()` function, but you won't necessarily get the corresponding row to it.

Other RDBMSs would actually do the same, but most forbid this by default (in can be forbidden in MySQL, too). You have two possibilities to fix this (actually there are more, but I'll restrict to two).

Either you put all columns you have in your `SELECT` clause which are not used in an aggregate function like `SUM()` or `MAX()` or whatever into the `GROUP BY` clause as well, like this:

```
SELECT hinfo.idx,
       hinfo.host_idx,
       hinfo.processor_load,
       hinfo.memory_total,
       hinfo.memory_free,
       hnames.idx,
       hnames.name,
       disks.hostinfo_idx,
       disks.id,
       disks.name,
       disks.size,
       disks.freespace,
       Max(hinfo.probetime)
FROM   systeminfo.hostinfo AS hinfo
       INNER JOIN systeminfo.hosts AS hnames
               ON hnames.idx = hinfo.host_idx
       INNER JOIN systeminfo.disksinfo AS disks
               ON disks.hostinfo_idx = hinfo.idx
GROUP  BY 
       hinfo.idx,
       hinfo.host_idx,
       hinfo.processor_load,
       hinfo.memory_total,
       hinfo.memory_free,
       hnames.idx,
       hnames.name,
       disks.hostinfo_idx,
       disks.id,
       disks.name,
       disks.size,
       disks.freespace
ORDER  BY hnames.name,
          disks.id
```

**Note that this query might get you a different result!** I'm just focusing on the problem, that you might get wrong data to the row you think holds the `MAX(hinfo.probetime)`.

Or you solve it like this (and this will get you what you want):

```
SELECT hinfo.idx,
       hinfo.host_idx,
       hinfo.processor_load,
       hinfo.memory_total,
       hinfo.memory_free,
       hnames.idx,
       hnames.name,
       disks.hostinfo_idx,
       disks.id,
       disks.name,
       disks.size,
       disks.freespace,
       hinfo.probetime
FROM   systeminfo.hostinfo AS hinfo
       INNER JOIN systeminfo.hosts AS hnames
               ON hnames.idx = hinfo.host_idx
       INNER JOIN systeminfo.disksinfo AS disks
               ON disks.hostinfo_idx = hinfo.idx
WHERE  hinfo.probetime = (SELECT MAX(probetime) FROM systeminfo.hostinfo AS hi
                                                INNER JOIN systeminfo.hosts AS hn
                                                ON hnames.idx = hinfo.host_idx
                                                INNER JOIN systeminfo.disksinfo AS d
                                                ON disks.hostinfo_idx = hinfo.idx
                          WHERE d.id = disks.id AND hn.name = hnames.name)
GROUP  BY disks.id,
          hnames.name
ORDER  BY hnames.name,
          disks.id
```

There's also a nice example in the manual about this: [The Rows Holding the Group-wise Maximum of a Certain Column](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html)

Comment: Ok, i now understand the problem, you answer is logical. However, i've got a problem with test. I believe there is need to add one more inner join in sub-select - to join hosts table in order to compare hnames.name with it ("h" table does contain only index of host, not the name). Or, compare of indexes is enough, like: "WHERE d.id = disks.id AND h.hosts_idx = hinfo.host_idx)" ?

Comment: Yes, you are right, misread the table names, yes. Corrected it in my answer. Note that I also added a link to an excellent example in the manual.

Comment: However, there is still a problem. "hnames.idx", "hinfo.host_idx", "disks.hostinfo_idx" are not available in sub-select. I believe they don't exist in this context. Shouldn't be join performed on local aliases - hi, hn and d ? Like "FROM systeminfo.hostinfo AS hi
                                                INNER JOIN systeminfo.hosts AS hn
                                                ON hn.idx = hi.host_idx
                                                INNER JOIN systeminfo.disksinfo AS d
                                                ON d.hostinfo_idx = hi.idx" ?

Comment: Or it does work after this little change. But it takes few minutes to perform this query ... Oh my.

Comment: I did also reduced the subselect query, because inner join is here unnecesary - in order to get the probe time for correct host, enough is to compare only host_idx columns. So i came with this: "(SELECT MAX(probetime) FROM systeminfo.hostinfo AS hi
                                               WHERE hi.host_idx = hinfo.host_idx)". However it still takes 30 seconds to perform such query on my database. I'am thinking if there is still a way to optimize the query or should i try completely another way to accomplish this.

Comment: Ok, i added few keys and i modified a query with some optimalizations (date restrictions). Now it's extremely fast!